# What is the best source to get 10 milliseconds time-series data for numerical computation?

Tags: time-series, numerical-methods, tick-data

I am working with 4th order Runge-Kutta method to compute a second order differential equation.

For the best accuracy, I need a 10 milliseconds *ohlcv* time-series data. I know that I can build it from scratch with historical tick data.

What would be the best source for free or paid samples?

Comment: Did you have a look at the many existing questions on data sources?

Comment: Is there a particular asset class that you're targeting?

Comment: @madilyn, just a sample, whatever it is.

Comment: @BouarfaMahi I mean if you're just making sure for correctness of numerical code, can't you just take daily OHLCV time series data, back out the returns series, scale down the returns and volume by taking the min of either the value divided with some factor or the floor function of the original, then cumulate the series again to get your "millisecond" scale data?

Comment: @madilyn no it is not possible because the relative error is  
 1e-05 and 1 for respectively Runge-Kutta  step size h of 10 and 100  milliseconds.

Comment: Finally i have found that some quantitative trading platforms offer free high resolution  historical market data and alternative data to develop and backtest quantitative strategies for algorithmic trading.